# I am trying to upload apk using google play developer api and it shows error "APKs are not allowed for this application."

Tags: publish, google-play-developer-api, androidpublisher

I am encountering an issue while trying to upload APKs for my Android application on the Google Play Developer Console. The error message I receive is "APKs are not allowed for this application." . I am able to create edits and get tracks but i am unable to upload apk.

I was expecting  instance of Apk in the response body but I am recieving this error.
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.nowcast.theharvestcenter/edits/05855292026155776303/apks?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ABPtcPqT-IoCCL9U1Gq4lYG4q-f2d3HabABHWOQi_o-4557KYlLnrlT6g09Nsvjd_teA-qkdfCYCGznmVm490K-KbWRAdcPlGkvJOQ5qbWnDsXiayQ
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "APKs are not allowed for this application.",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "APKs are not allowed for this application.",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"